# Publish Vector and Raster (GeoTiff) layer in Geoserver SLD

Tags: geoserver

Base layer and overlay layer are same when opening in ArcMap.

[image: Arcmap]

When publishing the same layers in geoserver , I get a shift of 27 meter.
I have attached an example image to show the problem.

[image]

Comment: Probably GeoServer is not recognizing both layers having the same coordinate-system? It is difficult to know without knowing more details in the GeoServer side.